# Cannot drop a constraint in MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access-2003

When using the SQL command :

**ALTER TABLE [Sessions] DROP CONSTRAINT [SessionAttendance]**

I get the exception error message "**Could not find reference.**"

The constraint exists, and shows in the system table of constraints for this user table.  How can I get this constraint to drop?

The database is in MS-ACCESS 2003 format. The application uses JET 4.0  I have several hundred instances which will need schema updates.  I have a utility program to generate the SQL, but it falls over when attempting the DROP CONSTRAINT action.

Comment: Did you try `ALTER TABLE [Attendance] DROP CONSTRAINT [SessionAttendance]` instead?

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  When I dropped the constraint from the foreign table (Attendance), the statement succeeded.  Apparently the constraint can be added to a primary table, but must be dropped from the foreign table.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by implications of Gord Thompson in comment suggestions.

The ALTER statement was being applied to the wrong table in the relation.

The constraint was originally Added to the Attendance table. However it shows up as an attribute of the Sessions table when using the "GetOleDbSchemaTable" method to list.

Per the following code excerpt:

```
Structure Relation
    Public Name As String
    Public PrimaryTableName As String
    Public PrimaryField As String
    Public PrimaryIndex As String
    Public ForeignTable As String
    Public ForeignField As String
    Public OnUpdate As String
    Public OnDelete As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim msg As String = String.Format("Name:{0} PT:{1} PF:{2} PI:{3}   FT:{4} FF:{5}", _
                Name, PrimaryTableName, PrimaryField, PrimaryIndex, ForeignTable, ForeignField)
        Return msg
    End Function
End Structure

Private Function ListRelations(tableName As String) As List(Of Relation)
    Dim relations As New List(Of Relation)
    Dim MySchemaTable As DataTable

    Dim dbConn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    dbConn.Open()

    MySchemaTable = dbConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys, _
               New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, tableName})

    Dim result As Boolean = False

    'List the table name from each row in the schema table.
    For Each row As DataRow In MySchemaTable.Rows
        Dim r As New Relation
        r.Name = row("FK_NAME")

        r.PrimaryTableName = row("PK_TABLE_NAME")
        r.PrimaryField = row("PK_COLUMN_NAME")
        r.PrimaryIndex = row("PK_NAME")
        r.ForeignTable = row("FK_TABLE_NAME")
        r.ForeignField = row("FK_COLUMN_NAME")
        r.OnUpdate = row("UPDATE_RULE")
        r.OnDelete = row("DELETE_RULE")
        Console.WriteLine(r.ToString)
        relations.Add(r)
    Next

    MySchemaTable.Dispose()
    dbConn.Close()
    dbConn.Dispose()

    Return relations
End Function
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Additional information added to answer objections from a commenter.  Credit for the Answer should go to Gord Thompson and commenter "Hal".